# Opening a new window using a link in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, hyperlink, click

How do I open a new window using a link in Tkinter?

For example, in a login window I want to add a link that says "New user? Click here" and when I click on "click here" it takes me to the register window.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Creating new `toplevel` windows works almost exactly the same as creating new widgets.

Toplevel windows are created using the `Toplevel` function:

```
t = Toplevel(parent)
```

Unlike regular widgets, you don't have to "Grid" a toplevel fo it to appear on screen. Once you've created a toplevel you can add children widgets within and grid them like in the main window. In other words toplevel behaves exactly like the automatic created root window.

To destroy a window use the method:

```
window.destroy()
```

Comment: Thank you , but is there a way to open a window by clicking a link  kinda like the picture in the question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can open new windows in tkinter with the tkinter.Toplevel() command.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Gui:
    """Gui class"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.new_window = tk.Button(master=self.root, text="Open new window", width=20, pady=4, command=self.new_window)
        self.new_window.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def new_window(self):
        """Create a new top level window"""
        new_window = tk.Toplevel()
        tk.Label(master=new_window, text="This is a new window").pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Gui()
```

Comment: Thank you , but is there a way to open a window by clicking a link kinda like the picture in the question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to open a new window and then bind it to that `Label`, for example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def newWindow():
    # Window object (top level)
    newWindow = Toplevel(master)
 
    # Title
    newWindow.title("New Window 1")
 
    # Geometry
    newWindow.geometry("300x300")

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(text="Hello!", width=50, height=10, master=root)
label.pack()
label.bind("<Button-1>", newWindow)
```

Comment: Thank you , but is there a way to open a window by clicking a link kinda like the picture in the question ?

Comment: @vaishnavgirish Then make the label text a link

Comment: You could modify the Label to `Label(text="Hello!", width=50, height=10, master=root, fg="blue", cursor="hand2")` to imitate an hyperlink.

Comment: Thank You very much !!!!!!

Comment: Glad it worked, make sure to accept the answer if it helped you so it can help other people in the future.

Comment: Will do so you code helped a lot